# How does System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler work? I dont understand what a cancelable event is?

Tags: .net, events, delegates

I just strated developing some forms in Windows Forms(C#) and I am having difficulty in understanding how System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler works and what a cancelable event means.

```
this.txtName.Validating += new
       System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txtBoxEmpty_Validating);
this.txtAddress.Validating += new
       System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txtBoxEmpty_Validating);
```

I would greatly appreciate if somebody can explain this event handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `TextBox's` validating event would go something like:

```
string previousText = this.Text;
string textThatWasEntered = this.GetInput();

// Update Text with inputted value
this.Text = textThatWasEntered;

// Validate inputted text, giving handlers a chance to cancel
CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs = new CancelEventArgs();
// call handlers, passing the CancelEventArgs so they can set .Cancel if needed
this.OnValidating(this, cancelEventArgs); 

// If cancelled, reset Text to previous value
if (cancelEventArgs.Cancel) {
   this.Text = previousText;
}
```

So, it's basically a way to stop the control from updating. You could use it for something like an email address validator:

```
void txtEmail_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
   string inputtedText = this.txtEmail.Text;
   if (!inputtedText.Contains("@")) {
      // No @ sign - deny update
      e.Cancel = true;
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid email address");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cancellable event is just that, something that you may programattically cancel.  In this case, you look to be attached to a textbox Validating event.  In the event handler (txtBoxEmpty_Validating), you'll receive a parameter of type CancelEventArgs which has a property named 'Cancel'

The whole point of this is that within your handler, if you set Cancel=true, then the text that was entered is considered invalid, and doesn't actually get set as the value of the textbox.

The difference being, say a KeyDown event could be cancelled, but a KeyPress may not, as it already occurred.